# Error while trying to send message to WMQ through java

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am trying to connect to a QM and send message to one of the queues, using below code:

```
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.jms.JMSException;

import com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.*;
import com.ibm.mq.commonservices.internal.trace.*;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;


public class MQConnect {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    Destination destination = null;
    Destination tempDestination = null;
    MessageProducer producer = null;
    MessageConsumer consumer = null;

    try {
        
        System.out.println(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);

      JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
      JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();

      cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "hostname"); 
      cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, port);
      cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, "channel");
      cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
      cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "QMName");

      connection = cf.createConnection();
      session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
      destination = session.createQueue("test_java_q");
      producer = session.createProducer(destination);

      long uniqueNumber = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
      TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(" " + uniqueNumber);
      connection.start();
      producer.send(message);

      }catch (JMSException jmsex) { 
          System.out.println(jmsex.getErrorCode()); 
          System.out.println(jmsex.getLinkedException().getCause()); 
          System.out.println(jmsex.getMessage()); 
          } 
    }   
}
```

The error I'm getting is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    com/ibm/msg/client/commonservices/trace/Trace
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory.<clinit>(JmsFactoryFactory.java:54)
    at MQConnect.main(MQConnect.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

I have the required jar files but I believe something is still missing from project references.
I have checked the jars and class specified in error is present in one of the jar files.

These are the jar files I have referenced:

```
com.ibm.mq.headers.jar
com.ibm.mq.jar
com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar
com.ibm.mq.tools.ras.jar
jms.jar
com.ibm.mqjms.jar
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar
com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar
```

There are also several other jars which are not com.ibm.*

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a class path related error. How are you specifying the class path for the execution. Is it by setting the `-cp` parameter on the `java` execution ?

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be picking and choosing MQ JAR files.  For IBM MQ v8.0 or higher, you should be using the `com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar` and `jms.jar` files.  That's it, just 2 files.  IBM has posted the com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar file on Maven (and use the most recent one). You can find com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mq/com.ibm.mq.allclient) and jms.jar from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jms/javax.jms-api/2.0.1).

If you are using IBM MQ v7.5 or lower (which all releases are out of support) then the correct JAR files are:

- connector.jar
- com.ibm.mq.jar
- com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar
- com.ibm.mq.headers.jar
- com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar
- com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar
- com.ibm.mqjms.jar
- jms.jar
- fscontext.jar
- jndi.jar
- jta.jar
- ldap.jar

Also, do NOT mix and match JAR files between different releases of IBM MQ.  It will cause you all kinds of headaches.

Finally, what is this line:

```
destination = session.createQueue("test_java_q");
```

It should be:

```
destination = context.createQueue("queue:///MY.TEST.QUEUE");
```

where 'MY.TEST.QUEUE' actually exists in the queue manager.  All MQ objects are case sensitive and MQ Best Practises says to use uppercase object names.  i.e. avoid lowercase names.

---

Updated Feb. 14, 2022.

You need to add some code to your program so we can see what is going on.

(1) Add the following MQLevel class (taken from my open source project [Universal File Mover](https://capitalware.com/ufm_overview.html)) to your project:

```
public class MQLevel extends MQJavaLevel
{
   /**
    * The constructor
    */
   public MQLevel()
   {
      super();
   }

   /**
    * Get the IBM name for the MQ JAR class.
    * @return
    */
   public String getName()
   {
      return queryValue(0);
   }

   /**
    * Get the version of the MQ JAR class.
    * @return
    */
   public String getVersion()
   {
      return queryValue(1);
   }
}
```

(2) Next add the following lines of code in your main method or at the very top of your code:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path").replace(';','\n'));
   
try
{
   MQLevel mql = new MQLevel();
   System.out.println("MQ JAR Version = " + mql.getName()+" V"+mql.getVersion());
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note: If you are on Linux/Unix rather than Windows then change the ';' (semi-colon) in the replace method to a ':' (colon).
i.e.

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path").replace(':','\n'));
```

Run your program with the updates, then update the original posting both with the new output.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I tried to re-run the code after deleting all jars except mentioned above for MQ v8.0 or higher, but still faced the same error. Also, jar files are referenced from MQ_Installation/java/lib folder which is the same version of MQ I'm trying to connect to.

Comment: I've seen this sort of error where the CLASSPATH  included older jar files in addition to newer.  You don't say what version you are using. I would suggest taking a MQ Java trace,  at the start of this file it will reveal the CLASSPATH of the running Java process.   Similar if you are using jar caching it could cause problems if it is not picking up the CLASSPATH changes.

Comment: Josh, Thanks for suggestions. I am currently trying to connect to MQ version 9.1.0.6.
Below are the jar files in CLASSPATH:
jms.jar
providerutil.jar
com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar

Comment: @Vaibhav see my updated posting.

Comment: @Vaibhav did you try taking a IBM MQ java trace? In the first few lines of the trace it will list the running classpath.  Can you update your question with this detail?